# Images display directory in php file

Tags: php, maintenance-mode

i have a maintenance page 503.php. I tried to get the images to be displayed but it did not show. I tried path and html img way, but it did not work. Below are the codes and also anyone helps me explain how to included images in php file?

My website images directory is like this:

on server: pulic_html/website/images

on local: website/images

php file dir: website/503.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>
 <?php
 header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
 header("Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
 header("Retry-After: 3600");
?>
</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url("../images/black-brick-wall-texture.jpg");
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div>
    <p style="text-alignment: middle"><img src="../images/still-under-construction.gif" width="306" height="350" alt="dang duoc bao tri" />"  </p>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px; color: #FFF;">
    <p>BSeveryday.vn hiện <span style="color: #F00">under maintenance</span>, please come back later <span  style="color: #F00">30p - 2 giở</span>.</p>
    <p>if you have any problem, please send me a message at: <span style="color: #00F">vandekhac@bseveryday.vn</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<p><img src="../images/under_construction.gif" alt="under maintenance" width="350" height="299" align="right" />" </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try without this(`../`). `url("images/black-brick-wall-texture.jpg")`;

Comment: I did, and it did not work on the server, and with file type php.

Comment: When a problem is solved, don't change the title, tick the checkmark next to the answer that solved it.  See also: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .htaccess file in the website's root directory insert the following line before your RewriteRule line::

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(gif|jpe?g|png)$
```

You may need to add css or js to that list of filetypes, depending on your holding page’s needs.

It may solve your problem.